# Google AppEngine FTS is skipping results

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I have a problem with FTS on Google AppEngine. I have indexed in the last 2 days over 1000000 enitities. 
Now I have the following problem: Some queries do not return my all my results.
Example: 
For the following query: **"owner=agent, month=10"** I get fewer results for the day of 31 than **"owner=agent, month=10, day=31"**.
(Both queries have the same order defined: by creation time as long descending)

It is possible that the indexes are still building for this documents? (The update finished 10 hours ago)
It is a known issue? If yes, is there a workaround?

**EDIT**
I have discovered that for every search I make I get only the last updated documents. The query returns only the last updated/inserted n (1000-2000) entries sorted by my SortOption field.
If I rise the *Number Found Accuracy* to 10000 then n is bigger and I get a larger set of entries sorted (but not all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/#Java_Overview):

> A call to search() can only return a limited number of matching
>   documents. Your search may find more documents than can be returned in
>   a single call. Each search call returns an instance of the Results
>   class, which contains information about how many documents were found
>   and how many were returned, along with the list of returned documents.
>   You can repeat the same search, using cursors or offsets to retrieve
>   the complete set of matching documents.